# How to stop connecting method in Core Bluetooth

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-bluetooth

When I call,

```
[self.CM connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
```

sometimes it don't get any answer.

How can I stop it or detect whether it's stopped?

Answer (score 2):

To stop scan:

```
[central stopScan]
```

Cancel connection:

```
[central cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral_object]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Device is not connected, cancel pending connection */


[centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheralManager];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for `centralManager:didFailToConnectPeripheral:error` in *CoreBluetooth.framework*.

Comment: I already added it.But it does not work.When [self.CM connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil]; can't connect with the peripheral it will keeping to connecting for a long time.I want to manually stop this.Is it possible??

Comment: I've seen again my code about BLE because I have to develop another app with it, and I've seen `stopScan`, methods of `CBCentralManager`.

Comment: Dose `stopScan` can stop the `connectPeripheral:peripheral` method??I think it can only stop the `scan` method.

Comment: I've never seen `didFailToConnectPeripheral` fire in real life.